# Can't find class for extended view?

Tags: android, class, android-layout, android-manifest

I'm extending the `Button` view to `MyButton` to add some bespoke methods, i.e.,

```
public class MyButton extends Button {

    public SignUpButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    // Bespoke methods etc.

}
```

and then in the layout xml

```
<com.package.mine.MyButton
        android:id = "@+id/button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />
```

This works - great! However, when I try and put the `MyButton` class as a `static` inner class in my activity the application keeps crashing, i.e., in the activity I define `MyButton` as

```
public static class MyButton extends Button {

    public SignUpButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    // Bespoke methods etc.

}
```

and I refer to it in the xml layout as

```
<com.package.mine.MyActivity.MyButton
        android:id = "@+id/button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />
```

The package in the manifest file is defined as `package="com.package.mine"`, and the logcat error is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.package.mine.MyActivity.MyButton" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.package.mine-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.package.mine-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need static?

Comment: Still learning, but everything I've read says that you ought to declare it as static when it's an inner class in the activity. I've tried it non-static but that doesn't work either.

Comment: is it an inner class? and you should use `<com.package.mine.MyButton` and your constructor to `MyButton`

Comment: I'm confused. `<com.package.MyButton` works when `MyButton` exists as its own file within the package (that makes sense to me). But as soon as I copy the class into the activity as an inner class, I would have thought you'd require `<com.package.MyButton$MyButton`, but intellij is autocompleting to `<com.package.MyButton.MyButton`????

Comment: coz  com.package.mine  is your package name and MyButton is your Custom button class name. SO you should have that class under the package name. what you are doing is wrong. Put your custom button class in a separate file. You are package name is not `com.package.mine.MyActivity`. It is `com.package.mine`.

Comment: Thanks, but not working. Neither `<com.package.mine.MyButton` nor `<com.package.mine.MyActivity.MyButton` works when the class is set as an inner class - get the error as shown above :(

Comment: i did ask you to put it under a new file as a separate class not as inner class read the  previous comment full :(. You would want your custom button to be used throughout your app. having it as a inner class is not good and it does not work. You may want o use custom button in other activities as well

Comment: Thanks. But I have been able to get it to work that way (see original question). I'm trying to work out how to get it to work when I set it as an inner class in the activity, or is that not possible? Trying to save file proliferation.

Comment: did you understand my comments you can't do that way

Comment: Great, thanks Raghunandan. So it's not possible to do it in the manner as I describe. Learning all the time! Appreciate your time.

Comment: its possible but not the way you are doing. you can have a inner class and then set the content of the custom view to the activity.

Comment: Understand the principle. What method is required to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`com.package.mine` is your package name and `MyButton`is your Custom button class name.

So you should have that class under the package name. What you are doing is wrong.

Put your custom button class in a separate file. Your package name is not `com.package.mine.MyActivity`. It is `com.package.mine`

You can do like this if you want an inner class

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyButton mb = new MyButton(this);
        setContentView(mb);
        mb.setText("hello");
    }
    public  class MyButton extends Button {

        public MyButton(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        @Override
        public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.setText(text, type);
        }
    }
}
```